Linux awk script commands
I'm working on a project to extract network info from tcpdump that requires many awk pipe commands for formatting prior to import into a database used for reporting, i.e.,:
tcpdump -tttt -vi any -c 100 | grep -v "Date:$(date +%F)\$" | awk '/^ +/{$1=$1;print q, $0; next} {q=$0}' | awk '{gsub(/\(|\)|>|,/, ""); print}' | awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="," | awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '$27=="incorrect" { for(i = 28; i < NF-1; i++) $i = $(i+4); NF -= 4 } { print }'| awk nnnn (more awk commands) > tcpdump.csv .
I've piped so many awk commands (20+), awk now fails (at least on my system) to completely execute and I now need 2 separate pipe command groups.  I'm new to awk but research suggests an option to add/execute the awk commands in sequence in a awk script file versus pipe command line ... is it possible and if so, how should the commands above and below be formatted in an awk script file:
awk nnnn (more awk commands) tcpdump.csv | awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{sub(/\.localdomain/,"")} 1'| awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{sub(/\.:.*/,"",$25)} 1' | awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{sub(/\.\..*/,"",$25)} 1' |  awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{sub(/localhost\.localdomain.*/,"localhost",$25)} 1' |  awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{ gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$23) }1' | awk 'BEGIN { FS =","; OFS = ","} {for (i = 24; i <= 24; i++) { $i = "" }; print}' > tcpdumpworking.csv
Review and assistance appreciated in advance.

It's unreasonable to ask us to blindly refactor that into a single script without at the very least an expected input and an expected output. At the very least. Please provide at least an example output of the tcpdump command and an example of tcpdumpworking.csv, and explain what the script does in your own words. It'll probably be easier to rewrite it completely, there's a lot of parsing going on and I suspect many commands could be joined toghether.

I'll second this. Show example input and corresponding desired output, and explain what the transformation is trying to achieve. (Leave your code in the question, because it'll help us understand where you're at.)

Review and guidance appreciated!  Sample data follows: $ cat data.csv  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 20-09-24,br0,B,UDP,length,127,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,device1,50222, 20-09-24,eth0,In,TCP,length,60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,167.99.127.131,52842,correct 20-09-24,br0,Out,TCP,length,60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,167.99.127.131,52842,correct The current awk commands remove rows without dates, incorrect, or invalid packets, remove special characters, verify column separations with commas, etc.  Both groups of awk pipe commands work correctly.  Sorry I wasn't clear, but my question is for running awk pipe commands ...

... in an awk script, i.e., awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{sub(/\.:.*/,"",$25)} 1' | awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{sub(/\.\..*/,"",$25)} 1' |  awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{sub(/localhost\.localdomain.*/,"localhost",$25)} 1' |  awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{ gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$23) }1' | awk nnnn (more awk commands) in awk --posix -f tcpdumpscript.awk tcpdump.txt > tcpdumpworking.txt similar to (if possible):

$ cat tcpdumpscript.awk  awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{sub(/\.:.*/,"",$25)} 1'  awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{sub(/\.\..*/,"",$25)} 1' awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{sub(/localhost\.localdomain.*/,"localhost",$25)} 1' awk nnnn (more awk commands) $

Quick clarifications: 1) data.csv (forgot to rename) is equivalent example to non-formatted tcpdump.txt (not ready for database import), 2) awk commands listed in tcpdumpscript.awk are on separate lines and presently accomplish required formatting using two awk pipe command groups, and 3) tcpdumpworking.txt is formatted version (ready for database import) of non-formatted tcpdump.txt.  I've identified examples for awk scripts but they show if statements or while/for loops and my current skills are unable generate a block of singular awk statement.  Hope this helps.

Danny please remove all those comments containing data dumps as they are almost completely unreadable. Instead, put the updates into your question, reflowing the question so that it's a readable whole (no "edit" statements - just make the thing readable)

Hi Chris.  Still learning, feedback appreciated, and I'll apply your recommendations next question.

After additional research, my solution to execute multiple commands inside awk script file is:
`$cat tcpdumpscript.awk
BEGIN {
Output field separator of comma
OFS=",";
(input?) field separator as comma
FS=",";
define our desired separator
sep=",";
}
Test print first line
{print "1st section of line " $1,$2,$3
};
Test print second line
{print "2nd section of line " $4,$5,$6
};
Test print third line
{print "3rd section of line " $7,$8,$9
};
Print entire line
print $0;
} #Stop awk commands processing tcpdump.txt
END{}`
